# saving records with text boxes combo boxes and datepicker and datagrid on the form

Tags: .net, sql-server-2012, vb.net-2010

when i click save on a order entry form nothing is prompted and form closes as it should do but no record in the SQL server database
 so its so long thought i would post the whole code

```
 Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Configuration

Public Class purchaseorderinput

    Public Sub SELECTText(ctr As TextBox)
        ctr.SelectionStart = 0
        ctr.SelectionLength = Len(ctr.Text)
    End Sub
    Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=StockMasterv5;Trusted_Connection=True"
    ' Dim connectionString As New SqlConnection(gstrDSN)
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim curDel As Decimal
    Dim curCom As Decimal
    Dim curFactor As Decimal
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strShop As String
    Dim strStock As String
    Dim strWarehouse As String
    Dim strStockCode As String
    Dim delid As Integer
    ' Create a DataSet
    Dim cbodata As New DataSet()
    Dim adata As New DataSet()
    Dim ddata As New DataSet()
    Dim pdata As New DataSet()
    Dim bdata As New DataSet()
    Dim cdata As New DataSet()
    Dim udata As New DataSet()
    Private detailsBindingSource As New BindingSource()
    Dim edata As New DataSet()
    Dim InsertCommand As New SqlCommand
    Dim UpdateCommand As New SqlCommand
    Dim DeleteCommand As New SqlCommand
    Dim StockDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblStock WHERE StockCode='" & strStock & "') Like '" & strStock & "*'))", connection)
    Dim SuppliersDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from tblSuppliers where SupplierRef ='" & strShop & "') LIKE '" & strShop & "*'))", connection)
    Dim WarehouseDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from tblWarehouses WHERE WarehouseRef LIKE '%" & strWarehouse & "%'", connection)
    'Dim DeliveryDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from tblDeliveries", connection)
    Dim DeliveryIDDA As New SqlDataAdapter("Select Max(DeliveryID) as MaxRef from tblDeliveries ", connection)

    Dim useridda As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT LoginCode from tblEmployee where DefaultEmp = 1", connection)
    '  Dim SettingsDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from tblCompanyDetails", connection)
    Dim SeasonDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT SeasonName from tblSeasons", connection)

    Private Sub PurchaseOrderinput_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        adata.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
        cbodata.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
        If Form1.txtMode.Text = "NEW" Then myNew()
        If Form1.txtMode.Text = "OLD" Then myOld()
        If Form1.txtMode.Text = "DELETE" Then myDelete()
        Try
            connection.Open()
            SeasonDataAdapter.Fill(cbodata, "tblSeasons")
            '  SettingsDataAdapter.Fill(adata, "tblCompanyDetails")
            ' cboCurrentSeason.DataSource = cbodata
            ' cboCurrentSeason.DisplayMember = "SeasonName"
            ' cboCurrentSeason.ValueMember = "SeasonName"
            For Each dRow As DataRow In cbodata.Tables("tblSeasons").Rows
                cboCurrentSeason.Items.Add(dRow.Item(0).ToString)
            Next

            connection.Close()

        Catch ex As SqlException
            Return
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub myNew()
        cmdAdd.Text = "Add"
        cmdCancel.Text = "Cancel"
        cmdClear.Text = "Clear"
        ' Dim dt As DataTable
        Dim DeliveryDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter
        DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 7
        DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "LineID"
        DataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = "DeliveryID"
        DataGridView1.Columns(2).Name = "StockCode"
        DataGridView1.Columns(3).Name = "TotalGarments"
        DataGridView1.Columns(4).Name = "Totalhangers"
        DataGridView1.Columns(5).Name = "TotalBoxes"
        DataGridView1.Columns(6).Name = "NetAmount"

        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(0).Visible = False
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(1).Visible = False
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(2).HeaderText = "Stock Code"
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(3).HeaderText = "Garments"
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(4).HeaderText = "Hangers"
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(5).HeaderText = "Boxes"
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(6).HeaderText = "Cost"
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(2).Width = "100"
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(3).Width = "80"
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(4).Width = "70"
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(5).Width = "70"
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(6).Width = "80"
    End Sub
    Private Sub myOld()
        Dim DeliveryDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from tblDeliveries", connection)
        cmdAdd.Text = "OK"
        cmdClear.Visible = False
        cmdCancel.Text = "Cancel"
        OLDRecord()
    End Sub
    Private Sub myDelete()
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim a As String
        Dim b As String
        i = Form1.DataViewer.CurrentRow.Index
        '  a = Form1.DataViewer.Item(7, i).Value
        ' b = Form1.DataViewer.Item(8, i).Value
        a = Form1.DataViewer.Item(0, i).Value
        b = Form1.DataViewer.Item(0, i).Value
        DeleteCommand.Connection = connection
        DeleteCommand.Connection.Open()
        DeleteCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        DeleteCommand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tblStockMovements WHERE MovementType ='1' AND Reference='" & a & "'"
        DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        DeleteCommand.Connection.Close()
        DeleteCommand.Connection = connection
        DeleteCommand.Connection.Open()
        DeleteCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        DeleteCommand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tblDeliveries WHERE DeliveryID='" & b & "'"
        DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        DeleteCommand.Connection.Close()
        DeleteCommand.Connection.Open()
        DeleteCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        DeleteCommand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tblDeliveryLines WHERE DeliveryID='" & b & "'"
        DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        DeleteCommand.Connection.Close()
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
    Private Sub cmdAddItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdAddItem.Click
        Dim rowNum As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
        ' TextBox22.Text = FormatCurrency(TextBox22.Text, 2, TriState.True)
        With DataGridView1

            .Rows(rowNum).Cells(0).Value = TextBox24.Text
            .Rows(rowNum).Cells(1).Value = TextBox12.Text
            .Rows(rowNum).Cells(2).Value = TextBox18.Text
            .Rows(rowNum).Cells(3).Value = TextBox19.Text
            .Rows(rowNum).Cells(4).Value = TextBox20.Text
            .Rows(rowNum).Cells(5).Value = TextBox21.Text
            .Rows(rowNum).Cells(6).Value = TextBox22.Text
            curDel = CDec(textbox6.Text)
            curCom = CDec(textbox7.Text)
            curFactor = (curDel + curCom)
            CalculateTotals()
        End With
        TextBox24.Text = ""
        TextBox18.Text = ""
        TextBox19.Text = ""
        TextBox20.Text = ""
        TextBox21.Text = ""
        TextBox22.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.LostFocus

    End Sub

    Private Sub txtCommission_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles textbox7.LostFocus
        textbox7.Text = FormatCurrency(textbox7.Text, 2, TriState.True)
        CalculateTotals()
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtDeliveryCharge_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles textbox6.LostFocus
        textbox6.Text = FormatCurrency(textbox6.Text, 2, TriState.True)
        CalculateTotals()
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdFindSupplier_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdFindSupplier.Click
        If TextBox13.Text = "" Then MsgBox("Please Enter a Supplier Reference", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Stock Master V2")
        If TextBox13.Text <> "" Then FindShop()
    End Sub
    Public Sub FindShop()
        Dim sql As String = "Select * from tblSuppliers where SupplierRef='" & TextBox13.Text & "'"
        Dim zdataa As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection)
        Dim dt As New DataSet
        zdataa.Fill(dt, "tblSuppliers")
        Dim dr As DataRow = dt.Tables(0).Rows(0)
        Try
            If dr.Table.Rows.Count - 1 > 0 Then
                MsgBox("Please Enter a Supplier Reference", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Stock Master v2")

            Else
                DataGridView2.DataSource = dt.Tables(0)
                TextBox14.Text = dr("SupplierName").ToString
            End If
        Catch ex As SqlException
            MsgBox("Please Enter a Supplier Reference", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Stock Master v2")
        End Try

    End Sub
    Public Sub FindWarehouse()

        Dim sql As String = "Select * from tblWarehouses where WarehouseRef='" & TextBox15.Text & "'"
        Dim zdataa As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection)
        Dim dt As New DataSet
        If TextBox15.Text = "" Then
            sql = "Select * from tblWarehouses"
        End If
        zdataa.Fill(dt, "tblWarehouses")
        Dim dr As DataRow = dt.Tables(0).Rows(0)
        DataGridView2.DataSource = dt.Tables(0)
        TextBox17.Text = dr("WarehouseName").ToString

        If dr("WarehouseType").ToString = "False" Then TextBox16.Text = "Active"

        If dr("WarehouseType").ToString = "True" Then TextBox16.Text = "Long Term"



    End Sub
    Public Sub FindStock()
        Dim sql As String = "Select * from tblStock where SupplierRef='" & TextBox13.Text & "'"
        Dim zdataa As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection)
        Dim dt As New DataSet
        If TextBox13.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Select A Supplier", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Stock Master v2")
            TextBox13.Select()
        End If
        zdataa.Fill(dt, "tblStock")
        Dim dr As DataRow = dt.Tables(0).Rows(0)
        DataGridView2.DataSource = dt.Tables(0)
        If dr.Table.Rows.Count - 1 > 0 Then
            TextBox18.Text = dr("StockCode").ToString
        Else
            MsgBox("Please Create Stock Record", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Stock Master v2")
        End If

        '   If dr("WarehouseType").ToString = "False" Then TextBox16.Text = "Active"

        'If dr("WarehouseType").ToString = "True" Then TextBox16.Text = "Long Term"
    End Sub
    Private Sub getStock()
        strStock = TextBox18.Text
        If Trim(strStock) <> "" Then
            connection.Open()
            StockDataAdapter.Fill(cdata, "tblStock")
            TextBox18.Text = cdata.Tables("tblStock").Rows(0).Item("StockCode")
        Else
            Call FindStock()
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub getWarehouse()
        strWarehouse = TextBox15.Text
        If Trim(strWarehouse) <> "" Then
            connection.Open()
            ' Dim str As String = "Data Source=.;uid=sa;pwd=123;database=master"
            ' Dim con As New SqlConnection(str)
            ' Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from logn where username like '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%'", con)
            ' Dim Adpt As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            ' Dim ds As New DataSet()
            ' If (Adpt.Fill(ds, "logn")) Then
            'DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

            'MessageBox.Show("match found")
            'Else
            '   MessageBox.Show("match not found")
            'End If
            WarehouseDataAdapter.Fill(bdata, "tblWarehouses")
            TextBox16.Text = bdata.Tables("tblWarehouses").Rows(0).Item("WarehouseName")
            connection.Close()
        Else
            Call FindWarehouse()
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub getshop()
        strShop = TextBox13.Text
        If Trim(strShop) <> "" Then

            connection.Open()
            SuppliersDataAdapter.Fill(adata, "tblSuppliers")
            TextBox14.Text = adata.Tables("tblSuppliers").Rows(0).Item("ShopName")
        Else
            Call FindShop()
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub TabPage2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TabPage2.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdFindWarehouse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdFindWarehouse.Click
        FindWarehouse()
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdFindStockCode_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdFindStockCode.Click
        FindStock()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox13_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox13.LostFocus
        FindShop()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox15_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox15.LostFocus
        FindWarehouse()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox18_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox18.LostFocus
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox18.Text
        FindStock()
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdAdd.Click
        If cmdAdd.Text = "Add" Then AddRecord()
        If cmdAdd.Text = "OK" Then Close()

    End Sub
    Private Function GetNextRef() As Integer
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim nextref As Integer

        DeliveryIDDA.Fill(ddata, "tblDeliveries")
        If ddata.Tables("tblDeliveries").Rows Is Nothing Then nextref = "1"
        If ddata.Tables("tblDeliveries").Rows.Count > 0 Then nextref = ddata.Tables("tblStockMovements").Rows(0).Item("MaxRef")
        TextBox12.Text = nextref + 1

    End Function
    Public Function AddRecord() As Boolean

        Dim blnTran As Boolean
        Dim lngNextRef As Integer
        AddRecord = False
        blnTran = True
        'Transfer Out 
        Dim username As String


        Dim stockcode As String
        Dim delgarm As String
        Dim delhang As String
        Dim delbox As String
        Dim delnet As String

        DeliveryIDDA.Fill(edata, "tblDeliveries")
        useridda.Fill(udata, "tblEmployee")
        username = udata.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0)
        Dim STR1 As String

        Try
            'Dim updatedb As String = " INSERT tblStock SET StockCode = @StockCode,SupplierRef = @SupplierRef,Season = @Season,DeadCode = @DeadCode,DeliveredQtyHangers = @DeliveredQtyHangers,RemoveFromClearance = @RemoveFromClearance,AmountTaken= @AmountTaken, CostValue = @CostValue,PCMarkUp = @PCMarkUp,ZeroQty= @ZeroQty,CreatedBy = @CreatedBy,CreatedDate= @CreatedDate WHERE StockCode = @StockCode"
            Dim insertdb As String = "INSERT INTO tblDeliveries(OurRef,SupplierRef,WarehouseRef,Season,TotalGarments,TotalBoxes,TotalHangers,NetAmount,DeliveryCharge,Commission,GrossAmount,DeliveryDate,DeliveryType,ConfirmedDate,Notes,Invoice,Shipper,ShipperInvoice,CreatedBy,CreatedDate) VALUES(@OurRef,@SupplierRef,@WarehouseRef,@Season, @TotalGarments, @TotalBoxes, @TotalHangers,@NetAmount,@DeliveryCharge,@Commission,@GrossAmount, @DeliveryDate,@DeliveryType,@ConfirmedDate, @Notes,@Invoice, @Shipper, @ShipperInvoice,@CreatedBy, @CreatedDate"


            Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            ' Create a DataSet
            Me.Validate()
            Dim com As New SqlCommand

            'Transfer Out
            lngNextRef = GetNextRef()
            com.Connection = connection
            com.Connection.Open()
            com.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            com.CommandText = insertdb
            com.Parameters.Add("@SupplierRef", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            com.Parameters.Add("@OurRef", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            com.Parameters.Add("@WarehouseRef", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            com.Parameters.Add("@Season", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            com.Parameters.Add("@TotalGarments", SqlDbType.Float)
            com.Parameters.Add("@TotalBoxes", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            com.Parameters.Add("@TotalHangers", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            com.Parameters.Add("@NetAmount", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            com.Parameters.Add("@DeliveryCharge", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            com.Parameters.Add("@Commission", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            com.Parameters.Add("@GrossAmount", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            com.Parameters.Add("@DeliveryDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            com.Parameters.Add("@DeliveryType", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            com.Parameters.Add("@ConfirmedDate", SqlDbType.Date)
            com.Parameters.Add("@Notes", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            com.Parameters.Add(" @Invoice", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            com.Parameters.Add("@Shipper", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            com.Parameters.Add("@ShipperInvoice", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            com.Parameters.Add("@CreatedBy", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            com.Parameters.Add("@CreatedDate", SqlDbType.Date)
            com.Parameters.Add("@SupplierRef", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox13.Text
            com.Parameters("@OurRef").Value = TextBox1.Text
            com.Parameters("@WarehouseRef").Value = TextBox15.Text
            com.Parameters("@Season").Value = cboCurrentSeason.Text
            com.Parameters("@TotalGarments").Value = textbox9.Text
            com.Parameters("@TotalBoxes").Value = textbox10.Text
            com.Parameters("@TotalHangers").Value = textbox11.Text
            com.Parameters("@NetAmount").Value = textbox5.Text
            com.Parameters("@DeliveryCharge").Value = textbox6.Text
            com.Parameters("@Commission").Value = textbox7.Text
            com.Parameters("@GrossAmount").Value = textbox8.Text
            com.Parameters("@DeliveryDate").Value = DateTimePicker1.Value

            com.Parameters("@DeliveryType").Value = cboType.Text
            If cboType.Text = "Confirmed" Then
                com.Parameters("@ConfirmedDate").Value = Now
            Else
                com.Parameters("@ConfirmedDate").Value = ""
            End If
            com.Parameters("@Notes").Value = TextBox23.Text
            com.Parameters(" @Invoice").Value = TextBox4.Text
            com.Parameters("@Shipper").Value = TextBox2.Text
            com.Parameters("@ShipperInvoice").Value = TextBox3.Text
            com.Parameters("@CreatedBy").Value = username
            com.Parameters("@CreatedDate").Value = Now
            com.ExecuteNonQuery()
            com.Connection.Close()
            connection.Open()
            DeliveryIDDA.Fill(edata, "tblDeliveries")
            delid = edata.Tables("tblDeliveries").Rows(0).Item("DeliveryID")
            TextBox12.Text = delid
            connection.Close()
            'Transfer In
            com.Connection.Open()
            For x As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
                'Copies1 = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value
                delbox = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(4).Value
                stockcode = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(2).Value
                delnet = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(6).Value
                delgarm = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(3).Value
                delhang = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(4).Value
                STR1 = "INSERT INTO DeliveryLines(DeliveryID,StockCode,DeliveredQtyGarments,DeliveredQtyBoxes,DeliveredQtyHangers,NetAmount) VALUES (@DeliveryID, @StockCode,@DeliveredQtyGarments,@DeliveredQtyBoxes,@DeliveredQtyHangers,@NetAmount)"
                Dim Comm As New SqlCommand(STR1, connection)

                Comm.Parameters.Add("@DeliveryID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = delid
                Comm.Parameters.Add("@StockCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = stockcode
                Comm.Parameters.Add("@DeliveredQtyGarments", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = delgarm
                Comm.Parameters.Add("@DeliveredQtyHangers", SqlDbType.Float).Value = delhang
                Comm.Parameters.Add("@NetAmount", SqlDbType.Float).Value = delnet
                Comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                '  DeliveryDataAdapter.Update(Me.edata)
            Next
            connection.Close()
            'Dim updatedb As String = " INSERT tblStock SET StockCode = @StockCode,SupplierRef = @SupplierRef,Season = @Season,DeadCode = @DeadCode,DeliveredQtyHangers = @DeliveredQtyHangers,RemoveFromClearance = @RemoveFromClearance,AmountTaken= @AmountTaken, CostValue = @CostValue,PCMarkUp = @PCMarkUp,ZeroQty= @ZeroQty,CreatedBy = @CreatedBy,CreatedDate= @CreatedDate WHERE StockCode = @StockCode"
            Dim insertstocmove As String = " INSERT INTO tblStockMovements (StockCode,SupplierRef,Location,LocationType,MovementQtyHangers,MovementQtyBoxes,MovementDate,MovementValue,Reference,TransferReference,CreatedBy,CreatedDate)VALUES(@StockCode,@SupplierRef,@Location,@LocationType,@MovementQtyHangers,@MovementQtyBoxes,@MovementDate,@MovementValue,@Reference,@TransferReference,@CreatedBy,@CreatedDate)"
            ' Create a DataSet
            Me.Validate()
            Dim com4 As New SqlCommand(insertstocmove, connection)
            'Transfer Out
            lngNextRef = GetNextRef()
            com4.Connection.Open()
            ' com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockmovementID", lngNextRef)
            com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockCode", TextBox1.Text)
            com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupplierRef", TextBox13.Text)
            com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", TextBox15.Text)
            com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocationType", TextBox16.Text)
            com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MovementType", "1")
            com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MovementQtyHangers", textbox10.Text)
            com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MovementQtyBoxes", textbox11.Text)
            com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MovementValue", textbox8.Text)
            com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reference", TextBox12.Text)
            com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TransferReference", TextBox12.Text)
            com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MovementDate", DateTimePicker1.Value)
            com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedBy", username)
            com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedDate", Now)
            com4.ExecuteNonQuery()
            com4.Connection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

        AddRecord = True
        Exit Function
    End Function

    Public Sub OLDRecord()


        Dim i As Integer
        i = Form1.DataViewer.CurrentRow.Index
        TextBox12.Text = Form1.DataViewer.Item(0, i).Value
        TextBox1.Text = Form1.DataViewer.Item(1, i).Value
        TextBox13.Text = Form1.DataViewer.Item(2, i).Value
        TextBox14.Text = Form1.DataViewer.Item(3, i).Value
        cboCurrentSeason.Text = Form1.DataViewer.Item(3, i).Value.ToString
        TextBox15.Text = Form1.DataViewer.Item(5, i).Value
        textbox9.Text = Form1.DataViewer.Item(6, i).Value
        textbox10.Text = Form1.DataViewer.Item(7, i).Value
        textbox11.Text = Form1.DataViewer.Item(8, i).Value
        textbox5.Text = Form1.DataViewer.Item(9, i).Value
        textbox6.Text = Form1.DataViewer.Item(10, i).Value
        textbox7.Text = Form1.DataViewer.Item(11, i).Value
        textbox8.Text = Form1.DataViewer.Item(12, i).Value
        '    DateTimePicker1.Text = Form1.DataViewer.Item(13, i).Value
        cboType.Text = Form1.DataViewer.Item(14, i).Value
        Label28.Text = Form1.DataViewer.Item(13, i).Value
        '    TextBox23.Text = Form1.DataViewer.Item(16, i).Value
        ' TextBox4.Text = Form1.DataViewer.Item(17, i).Value
        ' TextBox2.Text = Form1.DataViewer.Item(18, i).Value
        ' TextBox3.Text = Form1.DataViewer.Item(19, i).Value
        Try

            ' Create a DataSet.
            Dim data2 As New DataSet()
            data2.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

            ' Add data from the Customers table to the DataSet.

            ' Add data from the Orders table to the DataSet.
            Dim detailsDataAdapter As _
                New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from tblDeliveryLines Where DeliveryID='" & Form1.txtWatchId.Text & "'", connection)
            connection.Open()
            detailsDataAdapter.Fill(data2, "tblDeliveryLines")

            ' Establish a relationship between the two tables.
            '   Dim relation As New DataRelation("PurchaseOrders", _
            '     data.Tables("tblDeliveries").Columns("DeliveryID"), _
            '      data.Tables("tblDeliveryLines").Columns("DeliveryID"))
            '  data.Relations.Add(relation)

            ' Bind the master data connector to the Customers table.
            '   masterBindingSource.DataSource = data
            '  masterBindingSource.DataMember = "tblDeliveries"

            ' Bind the details data connector to the master data connector,
            ' using the DataRelation name to filter the information in the 
            ' details table based on the current row in the master table. 
            detailsBindingSource.DataSource = data2
            detailsBindingSource.DataMember = "tblDeliveryLines"
            connection.Close()

            ' com.Connection.Open()
            '  For x As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            ' STR1 = "SELECT * from tblDeliveryLines Where DeliveryID = '" & TextBox12.Text & "'"
            'Dim Comm As New SqlDataAdapter(STR1, connection)

            ' Delivery.Fill(edata, "tblDeliverylines")

            DataGridView1.DataSource = data2
            DataGridView1.DataMember = "tblDeliveryLines"
            DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
            DataGridView1.Columns.Item(0).Visible = False
            DataGridView1.Columns.Item(1).Visible = False
            DataGridView1.Columns.Item(2).HeaderText = "Stock Code"
            DataGridView1.Columns.Item(3).HeaderText = "Garments"
            DataGridView1.Columns.Item(4).HeaderText = "Hangers"
            DataGridView1.Columns.Item(5).HeaderText = "Boxes"
            DataGridView1.Columns.Item(6).HeaderText = "Cost"
            DataGridView1.Columns.Item(2).Width = "100"
            DataGridView1.Columns.Item(3).Width = "80"
            DataGridView1.Columns.Item(4).Width = "70"
            DataGridView1.Columns.Item(5).Width = "70"
            DataGridView1.Columns.Item(6).Width = "80"

            '   Next
            '    connection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

Not sure what is going on and how to fix this

Comment: You might want to start with handling exceptions to see what the message(s) might be.

Comment: Have you tried *reducing* the code to see if the problem persists?